# Why SRAM is commonly used in cache memory?

Tags: linux, microcontroller

I am studying about **RAM**, i don't understood why **Static RAM** is commonly used in cache memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A memory cache, sometimes called a cache store or RAM cache, is a
>   portion of memory made of high-speed static RAM (SRAM) instead of the
>   slower and cheaper dynamic RAM (DRAM) used for main memory. Memory
>   caching is effective because most programs access the same data or
>   instructions over and over. By keeping as much of this information as
>   possible in SRAM, the computer avoids accessing the slower DRAM. [<sup>†</sup>](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/cache.html)

The same reasoning is in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory#Clock_rate_and_power).

Answer (score 2):

Main reason is dynamic RAM are slower. As you know cache is for fast access so usually static RAM is better choice for cache memory.

Comment: SRAM. Is more expensive and much larger  than DRAM. 1T1C takes about a third than 6T, and it needs 1 bit-line

Answer (score 1):

Because it can be faster than dynamic RAM. And more expensive, otherwise it would be used everywhere.